# Using jq with 'contains' in a 'select' inside a 'del' is not working

Tags: json, jq

i try to remove some entries from a dict in a json. It works by using == but with contains it doesn't work.

Jq call working:

```
jq 'del(.entries[] | select(.var == "foo"))' input.json
```

Jq call not working:

```
jq 'del(.entries[] | select(.var | contains("foo")))' input.json
```

input.json:

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "var": "foo"
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "var": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "var": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

The result of `jq '.entries[] | select(.var == "foo")' input.json` and `jq '.entries[] | select(.var | contains("foo"))' input.json` is the same, so I think the two `del`-calls should also work.

Is this a bug in jq or did I something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This must be a bug as it seems to work perfectly on `jq` 1.6 ([try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/ZOSKY8kr--)).

If you're unable to update to `jq` 1.6 you should be able to use the following command instead, which I've successfully tested on `jq` 1.5 :

```
jq '.entries |= map(select(.var | contains("foo") | not))' file.json
```

Comment: Thank you!
I already assumed that is could be a bug. Because I can't update to 1.6 yet I will use your secand command!